# cgmanager fails on ubuntu 18 update

Tags: boot, 18.04, cgroup

I've just updated my Ubuntu 16 to 18.04.1 LTS, upon restart it fails to boot (completely unresponsive). I've tried booting in safe mode and works but I see there is an error on the `cgmanager`, specifically:

```
Failed to start Cgroup management daemon. See 'systemctl status cgmanager.service' for details.
```

Restarting doesn't seem to work. When I checked the cgmanager log (at upstart), the only message I see is:

```
initctl: Method "NotifyCGroupManagerAddress" with signature "s" on interface "com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6" doesn't exist
```

I'm not familiar with the upstart process, so my first guess would be that cgmanager failed to be updated with the rest of the packages.  I'd like an expert's opinion before venturing there.

Answer (score 6):

What I found is that the cgmanager package no longer exists in 18.04 (the search https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=cgmanager&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any returns an empty result)
But the package does not get removed during the upgrade, which is strange.

Comment: In my experience, Ubuntu very seldom uninstalls non-conflicting packages on upgrade with the assumption that the said package is important for the system and assuming that the dependencies are correct, it should continue working just fine.

Comment: It seems that `cgmanager` should have been removed not because it is unsupported but because it will conflict with `systemd`. For details, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1108189/50254

Answer (score 1):

after reading what  Mikko Rantalainen  wrote:

"
It seems that cgmanager should have been removed not because it is unsupported but because it will conflict with systemd. For details, see askubuntu.com/a/1108189/50254 – Mikko Rantalainen Jan 9 '19 at 7:02
"

running
`apt autoremove`
removed it

Comment: actually this solves the problem of the question correctly. it is not comment to author, it is my original solution, also giving credit to the source what gave me the idea

Comment: OK, you get my upvote for that – however, comments are deleted regularly, your answer would greatly benefit if you could [edit] it and include the details from Mikko’s comments.