# What is the best cgmanager alternative for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: software-recommendation, ram, administration, cgroup, resource-limiting

I was using package [`cgmanager`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=cgmanager) to automatically manage processes into memory cgroups in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS environment.

However, I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and package `cgmanager` is no longer available. Is there any known good alternative?

Background info: It seems that `cgmanager` was removed because it cannot live nicely with `systemd` ([bug 1649310](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1649310)).

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/q/1081319/50254

Answer (score 1):

According to [comment 20](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1649310/comments/20) in bug [1649310](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1649310) `cgmanager` was removed because it has been replaced by `systemd`. I guess `cgmanager` was removed also because it conflicts too hard with `systemd` as documented in [Debian bug 761389](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=761389).

Some history about `systemd` and `cgmanager` can be found at [LWN article about cgroups](https://lwn.net/Articles/575672/). According to that, Lennart Poettering does not want to support running `systemd` with any other `cgroup` manager (such as `cgmanager`).

So the answer seems to be one needs to convert any `cgmanager` configuration one has into `systemd` configuration. Unfortunately I cannot find any info about how to do that so probably the only way is to start reading `systemd` documentation and restart from the scratch.