# How to configure systemd to put all my browsers in a single cgroup

Tags: systemd, user-profile, resource-limiting

Long time ago I used `cgmanager` to put all my browsers (Opera, Firefox, Chrome) in a single cgroup and set max RAM usage limit for that group.

However, [modern `systemd` really doesn't want other programs messing up with the cgroups](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108189/50254) so how to configure this with modern Ubuntu?

**Basically I'm asking how to configure selected processes listed by `systemctl status session-$XDG_SESSION_ID.scope` to be automatically moved by systemd to user defined group with special limits?** For example, I'd like to define that if the process binary is
`/usr/bin/firefox` or `/opt/google/chrome/chrome` then it should be moved to my custom user cgroup called `mybrowsers`.

I'm also looking for a generic solution that doesn't depend on desktop environment or window manager doing this (I know that modern Gnome should create some groups automatically). I guess I could write a program to monitor new processes and then move them using systemd API but I assume there must be a way to do this by systemd, right? And any option that depends on polling process list seems workaround at best.

And I'm looking for a solution that is fully user defined if at all possible. And I'm aware that this can be done via `systemd-run` but that seems leaky solution because it's too easy to start a program the "wrong" way and then `systemd-run` is skipped.

Comment: In case you don't mind working behind systemd these articles may help: https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/faqsandhowtos/cgroups_instructions.html and https://raymii.org/s/articles/Limit_specific_process_memory_on_desktop_linux_with_cgroups.html